# JQuery-UI CSS List Position Bottom

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-position, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm having some trouble creating a sortable bar chart with jquery-ui and css. I'm having to use `float: left` on my `<li>` tags instead of `display: inline-block` to prevent the margins from messing up when the bars are dragged, but this means the bars valign to the top of the container instead of the bottom.

A bit of Googling tells me that the standard way to achieve 'float bottom' is to put `position: relative` on the container and then `position: absolute; bottom: 0px` on the elements, but doing this just makes the `<li>`'s stack on top of each other.

I'm not sure how to position the `<li>`'s separated horizontally and still have the jquery sortable working, or how to otherwise achieve this.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NaWsd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/NaWsd/1/)

JS

```
$('li').each(function () {
    $(this).css({
        bottom: $(this).css('height')
    });
});
```

CSS

```
li {
    background-color: red;
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5px;
    width: 15px;
    position:relative;
}
#sortable1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
}
```

Basically I'm going through each list item and setting their bottom positions to match their heights.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display: inline-block` and assign `!important` to `margin-right:5px` to stop the jQuery over writing it.

```
margin-right:5px !important;
```